# Upgrade from a new Pi3 to a newer Pi4 caused error ssh: Could not resolve hostname

Tags: pi-4, pi-3b+

I was using a Raspberry Pi3 successfully connecting from Win10 PC with hostname (ssh pi@hostname). Ping hostname worked also.

I took the Pi3 chip and placed it into a Pi4. IP address changed from 192.168.1.180 to 192.168.1.181. I can still connect with ssh pi@192.168.1.181 but I can no longer connect with ssh pi@hostname. Nor can I ping hostname (i.e., ''Could not resolve hostname'').

status/attempts so far:

- hostname command confirms it is known by ssh
- Verizon My Network display shows the hostname
- /etc/hostname and /etc/hosts both show hostname
- i've rebooted the raspberry, the pc and the router many times
- i've reinstalled os-lite a few times (deleting .ssh\know_hosts before each attempt)
- i've tried using sudo raspi-config
- i've tried changing the hostname to hostname2 and back
- i noticed .ssh\known_hosts now only has one line with 192.168.1.181 ecdsa-sha2-nistp256... (with Pi3 it had two lines with hostname on the 2nd line), so i duplicated the 192.168.1.181 key with a 2nd hostname line ... no dice

Frustrating since it worked perfectly with Pi3.

Comment: If you want help you have to paste real data - not try to hide information (which is private anyway) and explain WHAT YOU DID.

Comment: `i've tried changing the hostname to hostname2 and back` does `hostname2` work if you DONT change it back? I'd also remove `.ssh\known_hosts` file on the client

Comment: jaromanda ... hostname2 didn't work and i have consistently removed known_hosts. milliways ... I'll post more details after trying andrew's approach below.

Comment: Andrew's arp -d * worked after I also performed sudo update. Thanks all for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clear the name cache in Windows.

Open an command line windows as an administrator and issue:

```
ipconfig /flushdns
```

If that does not work try:

```
nbtstat –R
```

Make sure that all entries for the machine name AND IP address (IPv4 and IPv6) are removed from the known_hosts file on the Windows PC.

You can also try `arp -d *` if the first two do not work.